# Animating a background from image to fill

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menu with a black to transparent gradient. When I hover the menu, I'd like to turn it into a completely black fill. Why isn't the following working?

```
$('#topmenu').hide().animate({
    'height': 'toggle'
    }, "slow").hover(function() {$(this).animate({ 'opacity' : 1 }).css( 'background' , 'rgb(0,0,0)', 'box-shadow' , "0px 5px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)" );}, function() {$(this).animate({ 'opacity' : 0.6  }).css( 'background' , "url('<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/topmenu_bg.png') repeat-x" );});
```

the menu's bg image is set through the stylesheet with the property 'background'.

Thank you.

Comment: Fixed :) but box-shadow property is still not applying at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not this plain CSS?

```css
#topmenu {
    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,black,transparent);
    background-color:transparent;
    transition:background-color 1s ease;
    /* vendor-specific alternatives follow */
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,black,transparent);
    -webkit-transition:background-color 1s ease;
}
#topmenu:hover {
    background-color:black;
}
```

Plain CSS is immeasurably faster than jQuery, both figuratively and literally since I have no idea how to measure CSS "speed" XD

Comment: Works in everything down to IE7. The fade effect works in all up-to-date browsers, but since it's eye-candy and a non-essential feature, compatibility is not something to get hung over on.

Answer (score 0):

To set multiple css properties you have to pass an object with the properties

```
$('#topmenu').hide().animate({
    'height': 'toggle'
    }, "slow").hover(function() {$(this).animate({ 'opacity' : 1 }).css({'background': 'rgb(0,0,0)', 'box-shadow': "0px 5px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)"});}, function() {$(this).animate({ 'opacity' : 0.6  }).css('background', "url('<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/topmenu_bg.png') repeat-x");});
```